# android sqlite nullpointer error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am working on an android project that requires a database.  The issue that I am having is when I go to start it up, i get a nullpointerexception error.  Going through the logcat, I have narrowed it down, to when the database updating, and trying to open.  Is this normal or am I over looking somthing?
logcat:

```
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity ComponentInfo{arch.field/arch.field.ChooseSite}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at arch.field.BmDb$DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(BmDb.java:96)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:132)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at arch.field.BmDb.open(BmDb.java:110)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at arch.field.ChooseSite.onCreate(ChooseSite.java:30)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-12 15:41:33.810: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(354):     ... 11 more
```

OnUpgrade code:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) 
       {
        Log.d("MonkeyDatabase","DbUpdater");
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_SITE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_UNIT_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_BONESHELL_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_CERAMIC_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_LITHIC_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
        }
```

Open code:

```
public BmDb open() throws SQLException
{
    Log.d("Database","open");
    db= BmDb.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

more code:

```
public BmDb(Context context)
{
    this.context= context;
    BmDb= new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);

}
```

this is the code from the ChooseSite file(with line numbers):

```
 final BmDb db=new BmDb(this);
    db.open(); **this is the line mentioned in my logcat**
    final Cursor c= db.GetSite();
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            sites(c);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

any suggestions on what I am over looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from this code

```
 final BmDb db=new BmDb(this);
db.open(); **this is the line mentioned in my logcat**
final Cursor c= db.GetSite();
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        sites(c);
    }while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

call this mehod twice    **db.open();**   put this in try{}catch{} black.

as follows  try{db.open();db.open();}catch(){}

Comment: why would that help correct it?  It worked, but just through up another error, and that one would be with my GetSite code, which is:

public Cursor GetSite()
 {
  return db.query(TABLE_SITE_NAME, new String[]{KEY_SITEID, KEY_SITENAME, KEY_SITELOC}, null, null, null, null, null);
 }
I am new to using SQLite with android, but from all the tutorials I have found, this is the common form.  Did I mark it wrong?

Comment: looking at the android developer site this I found two instances of a cursor query.  One with 8 parameters the other with 7.  I am using the 7 paramater one, which is as follows:

public Cursor query (SQLiteDatabase db, String[] projectionIn, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String sortOrder)

As far as I can tell, I am following it correctly.  Is there somthing that I am missing?

Comment: Ok, I am feeling stupid.  Why does a try{}catch(){} statement make all the difference?  That also fixed my other problem that I just commented on.  I also found, that I only need to call the db.open() once in the try{}catch{}.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onUpgrade`

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) 
       {
        Log.d("MonkeyDatabase","DbUpdater");
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_SITE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_UNIT_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_BONESHELL_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_CERAMIC_NAME);
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists "+TABLE_LITHIC_NAME);
         //onCreate(db);
         onCreate(arg0);
        }
```

`onUpgrade()` is called, if the database version is increased in your application code. check your code ..

Comment: the code to upgrade, is the marked in the actual program or would it be in my database file at the top; which I call VERSION?